# Adding shapes next to other shapes inside a tablelayoutpanel cell c# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, tablelayoutpanel

I'm quite new in .NET applications and I am trying to create a `TableLayoutPanel` with a `Label` and two circles:

[image]

For doing this, I am creating objects with a label and 2 circles and from above (where I have the TableLayoutPanel) I am trying to add those elements to a cell:

```
this.cellTableLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(this.devList[rowCount].devNameLabel, 0, rowCount);
this.cellTableLayoutPanel.Controls.Add(this.devList[rowCount].circle_in, 0, rowCount);
```

Elements: (Label devNameLabel, System.Windows.Shapes.Ellipse circle_in)

I can't figure out how to do this since it doesn't let me add the circle to the table cell. I would like to add the 3 items and add a margin to the left of the cell to set their position.

I have been searching for a while but I haven't found how to perform this. Does anyone knows? Thank you very much!

Comment: Elllipse does not derive from the Control class so can't be put in a table cell.  Consider creating a UserControl instead.  Or, more sensibly, derive your own class from Control and use its Paint event to draw this stuff.  Makes your UI a *lot* faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Ellipse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.ellipse(v=vs.110).aspx) is a WPF element and can not be directly hosted on windows forms controls, because it's not a `Control`.

**What's the equivalent of WPF *Ellipse* in Windows Forms?**

In Windows Forms, to have a shape on form, you can use [Visual Studio PowerPacks Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488277.aspx) like Line, Oval and Rectangle which are `Shape` component.

You can drop a `Shape` on `Form` or a `Panel` and use them. But even using a PowerPack `Shape` You can not host a `Shape` directly in a `Control` using code.

*Note 1:* While using designer you can drop a `Shape` on `Form`, but for `TableLayoutPanel` you can not drop a `Shape` using designer on `TableLayoutPanel`!

*Note 2:* Also when trying to add a `Shape` to `Controls` collection using the code, you will see you can not add it to `Controls` collection!

**Using designer, why I can host *Shape* in *Form* or in a *Panel* but not in a *TableLayoutPanel***?

In fact when you drop a shape on the form, the designer creates an invisible `ShapeContainer` that owns the `Shape`. The `Shape` will be drawn on surface of the `ShapeContainer` and the `ShapeContainer` is hosted on `Form` or `Panel`.  It's the designer trick.

For `TableLayoutPanel` this feature is not implemented in designer.

**How can I add a Shape to Controls collection using Code?**

You can add the `Shape` to a `ShapeContainer` and then add the `Panel` to `TableLayoutPanel`:

```
var container = new ShapeContainer();
var oval = new OvalShape(container) { Width = 20, Height = 20 };
this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(container, 0, 0);
```

**Is there any other alternative?**

Yes, as an alternative, you can create your custom Oval control simply by deriving from a `Control` and overriding `OnPaint` method.